# The color variations of Mirabilis Jalapa flowers

Tags: flowers

I have few Mirabilis Jalapa plants on the side of  my yard. The colors of their flowers are pink, white,yellow, and orange. But,only the plant with the orange flowers grow well, while the others seem to dying no matter I do. Maybe because of too much watering or the lack of sunshine and wind nowadays. Is there a solution for these ?. O yes, back to the original topic. Could I make a multicolor flower (in a single flower) by using these single-colored flower plants ? Is it true that a single mirabilis jalapa flower could contain 4 or 5 distinct colors ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a photo your existing Mirabilis to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Four-o'clocks have 3 basic colors, red, white and yellow. But they cross so there are 3 mixed colors .But the colors tend to be distinct in each flower ; so there is not a solid pink -there is red with white patches and there is white with red patches.  Some plants will show all 3 colors. The flowers on a bush are not all the same ( using the same red/white example) ; that is some will be mostly red with some white and some will be mostly white with some red. In my location the red seems to be more dominant , more than half of my bushes are red or red + another color although I prune out reds. Also ,mixed color plants will produce some pure ( red,white, or yellow ) seeds.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, Indonesia, as far as I know all four-o'clock plants all have single-colored flowers. So, here  a four-o'clock plant with red flowers will always produce red colors and only red colors, same for white, yellow, and orange colors. Here, four-o'clock plants with orange flowers are very very rarely seen(!). The only multi-color flowers I found here are red color with white patches/dots , or white color with red patches / dots. I observed that four-o'clock plants will grow well and have large leaves and flowers if there are enough sunshine, wind , and water.